# Is this solution correct? Eigenvector problem.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Find the eigenvectors of :$$\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$$ Finding the characteristic equation, we can write \begin{align*}
det(A-\lambda I) &= 0 \\
\begin{vmatrix}-\lambda&1&0&0\\1&-\lambda&0&0\\0&0&-\lambda&1\\0&0&1&-\lambda\end{vmatrix}&=0\\
-\lambda\begin{vmatrix}-\lambda&0&0\\0&-\lambda&1\\0&1&-\lambda\end{vmatrix} - \begin{vmatrix}1&0&0\\0&-\lambda&1\\0&1&-\lambda\end{vmatrix} &= 0\\
-\lambda(-\lambda(\lambda^2-1))-(\lambda^2-1) &= 0\\
-\lambda(-\lambda^3+\lambda)-\lambda^2+1 &= 0 \\
\lambda^4-\lambda^2-\lambda^2+1&=0\\
\lambda^2(\lambda^2-1)-1(\lambda^2-1)&=0\\
(\lambda^2-1)(\lambda^2-1) &= 0 \\
\lambda &= -1, 1\\
\end{align*} Now, finding the eigenvectors \begin{align*}
\lambda = 1, \begin{bmatrix}-1&1&0&0\\1&-1&0&0\\0&0&-1&1\\0&0&1&-1\end{bmatrix}\vec{v}_1&= 0\\
\begin{bmatrix}-1&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&-1&1\\0&0&1&-1\end{bmatrix}\vec{v}_1&= 0\\
\begin{bmatrix}-1&1&0&0\\0&0&1&-1\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&1&-1\end{bmatrix}\vec{v}_1&= 0\\
\begin{bmatrix}-1&1&0&0\\0&0&1&-1\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\vec{v}_1&= 0\\
\therefore \vec{v} &= (1,1,0,0)\\
\lambda = -1, \begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&0\\1&1&0&0\\0&0&1&1\\0&0&1&1\end{bmatrix}\vec{v}_1&= 0\\
\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&1&1\\0&0&1&1\end{bmatrix}\vec{v}_1&= 0\\
\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&0\\0&0&1&1\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&1&1\end{bmatrix}\vec{v}_1&= 0\\
\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&0\\0&0&1&1\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\vec{v}_1&= 0\\
\therefore \vec{v} &= (-1,-1,0,0)\\
\end{align*} Therefore, all of this matrix's eigenvectors are spanned by (1,1,0,0) and (-1,-1,0,0).

**Is this correct? I feel like there should be more, specifically (1,-1,0,0) corresponding to $\lambda = -1$, but I could be wrong.**

Comment: It should be very easy to check your answer to this question using software like Matlab or Octave. If you have either of those, try running the code: A=[0 1 0 0;1 0 0 0;0 0 0 1;0 0 1 0];[V,E]=eig(A). When I do that I find that there are just two eigenvalues but that both eigenspaces are two dimensional.

Comment: Notice that (1,1,0,0) = -1 (-1,-1,0,0) so technically you only have one independent eigenvector.

Comment: @Riley. In addition to Kitters answer: A set of eigenvectors is supposed to be linear independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eigenvalues you got are right. However, the eigenvectors you got are not quite right.

For $\lambda = 1$, solving $(A-I)x=0$, you can get two different particular solutions, and they are $x_1 = (1,1,0,0)^{T}$ and $x_2 = (0,0,1,1)^{T}$. Similarly you can get two different particular solutions for $(A+I)x=0$, and they are $x_3 = (1,-1,0,0)^{T}$ and $x_4= (0,0,1,-1)^{T}$. So you have four eigenvectors, $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, and $x_4$.

Comment: No the eigenvectors OP gave are not right. The second one $(-1,-1,0,0)$ is not an eigenvector for $\lambda=-1$. (It happens to be an eigenvector for $\lambda=1$, but that is more of an accident; the point is that finding a solution of the system for $\lambda=-1$ was just not done correctly.)

Answer (score 5):

You are doing more work than is necessary. The structure of $P$ can be
used to simplify the problem. Note that $P$ has the form
$\begin{bmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0 & A \end{bmatrix}$, where
$A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

So it is sufficient to find the eigenvectors of $A$ and combine them to get
the four eigenvectors of $P$.

By inspection, $A$ has eigenvectors $v_1=(1,1)^T$ and $v_2=(1,-1)^T$, so four eigenvectors will be $(v_1^T,0)^T $, $(v_1^T,v_1^T)^T $, $(0, v_2^T)^T $, $(v_2^T,v_2^T)^T $.

Comment: Note that a structure of the form $\begin{bmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0 & B \end{bmatrix}$ with $A,B$ square would allow this reduction, combining the eigenvectors from $A$ and $B$ (each extended with zeros as appropriate). The fact that $A=B$ is just another coincidence which makes this even easier.

Answer (score 3):

At the moment you have one linearly independent eigenvector.

You may observe that (-1,-1,0,0) doesn't actually fit the bill for the second eigenvector, but (1,-1,0,0) does since (-1,-1,0,0) doesn't actually give zero when multiplied by the second set of matrices.

You should be careful to note that your eigenvalues are degenerate so you may have multiple eigenvectors per eigenvalue. This is indeed the case, you can note this by solving for (0,0,a,b) which has an eigenvalue of 1 or -1.

Answer (score 3):

You have found the correct eigenvalues, but you have not found all of the eigenvectors.

Notice that for each of your eigenvalues, you have solved the matrix down to echelon form (almost).

For $\lambda = 1$ it should be
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 & -1\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
When you want to find the eigenvectors for this eigenvalue, think about how many free variables you have. That should be the number of linearly independent eigenvectors you can find for this eigenvalue.

You can follow this same approach with $\lambda = -1$.